# set cargo profile for workspace members but not dependencies?

Tags: rust-cargo

according to the docs (https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#overrides), it's possible to configure a profile to treat non-workspace-dependencies differently, e.g. with

```
# Set the default for dependencies.
[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 2
```

However, I'd like to do the other way around, and set flags for all my workspace members (but not for dependencies). Is this possible? It's not described in the docs.